# Microsoft.vshup.server.httphostx64.exe has stopped working on VS 2015 Community Edition update 3 when run project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, vs-community-edition

I recent faced problem in visual studio 2015 community edition update 3 while running project. I am running VS in windows 10.

The below popup error message is shown frequently when running project.

[image]

I have already follow the instruciton found on internet but it did not work in my case. So i uninstalled visual studio and reinstalled but it didnot work.

Do you have any solution?

Should i have to reinstall my OS to fix it?

Comment: create a dump (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx) and analyze it with windbg. if you can't see anything useful, submit it to MS via the IDE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt632287.aspx and upload the dmp to MS

Comment: @magicandre1981 thank you for your response. I just delete the VsHub folder of C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared/ and it works fine now but i don't know the real cause of this issue.